# Python rearrange the grouped diction

Tags: python

I am trying to develop a code and half of it is done, I am grouping my diction. I want to create a function to go back to the a_dict from b_dict
I want to print it as this;

Expected output;

```
a_dict:  {'A': 1, 'B': 2, 'C': 3, 'D': 1, 'E': 2, 'F': 3} # Original Diction
Grouped dict:  {1: ['A', 'D'], 2: ['B', 'E'], 3: ['C', 'F']} # Grouped Diction
Expected dict: {'A': 1, 'D': 1, 'B': 2, 'E': 2, 'C': 3, 'F': 3} # Expected second output with go_back function. Current output can not do this
```

Code:

```
a_dict = {'A': 1, 'B': 2, 'C': 3, 'D': 1, 'E': 2, 'F': 3}
print('a_dict: ', a_dict)


def fun_dict(a_dict):
    b_dict = {}
    for i, v in a_dict.items():
        b_dict[v] = [i] if v not in b_dict.keys() else b_dict[v] + [i]
    return b_dict


def go_back(b_dict):
#
# Need a function to convert b_dict to c_dict to go back as the expected output
# 

b_dict = fun_dict(a_dict)
print('Grouped dict: ', b_dict)

c_dict = fun_dict(b_dict)
print('Went to the original dict: ', c_dict)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `go_back` you want could be like this:

```
def go_back(b_dict):
    r = {}
    for k, vv in b_dict.items():
        for v in vv:
            r[v] = k
    return r
```

Result:

```
Went to the original dict:  {'A': 1, 'D': 1, 'B': 2, 'E': 2, 'C': 3, 'F': 3}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a proposal:

```py
def go_back(b_dict):
    return {e: k for k, v in b_dict.items() for e in v}
```